# How Can i open different files using expres.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm starting a journey with node.js and frameworks and I get big problem. I set up API on localhost:3000 and I wanna open different files by adding to URL word for example localhost:3000/quiz.
I used command  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
but i only get,, Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Darek\Desktop\Frontend\Quiz api\index.html'"

Thanks

CLOSED

EDIT:
[Routes files called quiz.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP4mw.png)

[Index.js server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bgMZ.png)

Comment: The error means that the file you are asking to send doesn't exist, may be you are giving wrong path. show the folder structure of your project in question (a screenshot may be) to better understand the problem.

Comment: @Rajan i updated quetion with screenshots.

Comment: try this `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));`

Comment: still this same error

Comment: add this line in index.js `console.log(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));` to see what value it prints

Comment: Okey it was problem with dirname, the path was on folder ..../Quiz api/routes/public/index.html

Comment: If your problem was solved, you should close this question or post an answer explaining what was the mistake or wrong assumption you made (you can post ans after two days of posting the question.)